# Decimal rounding issue while calculating angle of triangle

Tags: javascript, math, decimal

I am creating three angles. These angles creates a triangle.I want to show calculated angle in my canvas, for that I am calculating angle and rounding off for showing.While calculating the angle's ,  I am rounding off the decimal digits using `Math.round().`

So if I got `65.25, 70.36, 44.39 degree` as value of three angles and after rounding off it will be `65,70,44,which become 179 degree instead of 180 degree`(One degree is missing here).How can I solve this problem ?
Here are some images for reference

[image]

Comment: Round the display value only, not the calculated value.

Comment: @Diodeus but in display we will get 65,70 and 44 values, which anre not completing 180 degree of triangle.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to compute the third angle (rounded) based upon the other two, rather than simply rounding them all as you have done.  For instance:

```
var th0 = 65.25;
var th1 = 70.36;
var th2 = 44.39;

var th0r = Math.round(th0);
var th1r = Math.round(th1);
var th2r = 180.0 - th0r - th1r;
```

This will force `th0r + th1r + th2r` to always sum to 180.  You can become a little more sophisticated by picking the best angle to compute from the other two, but this will probably suffice for most applications.